# Upload clocking script

Tags: unix, scripting, cron

How can I make a script that, once a day, will upload a file via ftp to several different servers, then take note (in a log) of how much time the uploads took?

Thanks to Rajax I have the cronjob set up to execute this so far as the script, let's say it's called ftpScript.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

HOST='ftp.users.qwest.net'
USER='MYUSERNAME'
PASSWD='MYPASSWORD'
FILE='filename.gif'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
put $FILE

quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Where do I put this part?

```
time -a output.log ftpScript.sh
```

Comment: Add another script cronJob.sh which runs the time command and then run that as the cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cron](http://news.softpedia.com/news/CRON-Guide-35882.shtml) to execute a script once a day.

Use command-line ftp to upload the files and the [time](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm) command to time how long it took.

Appending time output to log:

```
time -a output.log ftpScript.sh
```

Comment: Thanks James, I was going to ask the same question!