# How to make a cronjobbable script to clock uploads?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I asked a similar question over here:([Upload clocking script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495604/upload-clocking-script)), but then changed it and realized it's a different question now.

I want to make a script called uploadtimer.sh which uploads files to various hosts and then notes the time the upload takes in a log file.  Thanks to those who have helped me, I have a partial solution but I'm stuck:

I used this as a crontab (testing it for the first ten minutes after 11 am)

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10     11     *     *     *          /usr/bin/time -a /usr/local/apache/sites/$MYEMPLOYER/upload_test/output.log  /usr/local/apache/sites/$MYEMPLOYER/upload_test/uploadtimer.sh
```

upload_test/ has these files in it:

upload_test/output.log
upload_test/uploadtest.gif
upload_test/uploadtimer.sh

output.log is a text file that I renamed as a .log file.  It's blank.  Before I put it there, I was getting messages that said "this file doesn't exist".  I thought it'd create one for me but I guess not.  After I created it, it kept saying in the crontab mails that I couldn't write to it until I changed its permissions, so I did.

uploadtest.gif is a gif

uploadtimer.sh is this:

```
#!/bin/sh

HOST='--myhost--'
USER='--login--'
PASSWD='--password--'
FILE='uploadtest.gif'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
put $FILE

quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

The message that cron sends to me is:

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.02elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+253minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

But no ftp has taken place and nothing it written in output.log.

Comment: +1 for "cronjobbable" - Lewis Carroll would be proud.

Comment: Does the "/usr/bin/time -a ... uploadtimer.sh" command work by itself at the shell?  If so, then the issue might involve the way cron is set up.  The scripts themselves are okay - maybe you should accept one of the answers here and post a new question about cron... (more people will see the new question about cron, but not come back to this one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another script that runs the second command. Call the second script from cron.

You will need to make sure you are using absolute paths for everthing because cron starts in a different directory than the script.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions:

- **Where do I put this part, which tells it to save the data to a log?**

  You edit your crontab file to add a cron entry.  The cron entry contains information regarding what command to run and when to run it.  For example, here is a cron entry that you might use:

  `0   2   *   *   *   /usr/bin/time -a ~/output.log ~/uploadtimer.sh`

  This entry says to run the command at 2AM every day (minute 0, hour 2, every day of the month, every month, every day of the week).  For more info on the crontab syntax, you can check out http://www.adminschoice.com/docs/crontab.htm .

  To make a cron entry, use the command `crontab -e` which will load up a vi text editor.  Enter the line above and then save it.  This creates the cron job.  If you don't know vi, just follow this:

  - from the shell, enter `crontab -e` to start editing
  - press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter Insert mode
  - enter the line as above
  - press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit Insert mode
  - press <kbd>:</kbd> to switch to Command mode - you will see the cursor at the bottom of the screen
  - enter <kbd>wq</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> - this **W**rites and **Q**uits the file.  You should see a message like `crontab: installing new crontab`.

  If you run into any problems using vi, use <kbd>ESC</kbd> a few times to exit whatever mode it's in, do <kbd>:</kbd> to enter Command mode, and then <kbd>q!</kbd> to force a quit (i.e., quit without saving anything), and then try again from the beginning.

- **It refers to the script itself so does it need to be separate from the script?**

  Yes.

Comment: What version of cron requires tabs and not spaces?

Comment: Sorry about that - I learned it that way from somewhere and just stuck with it that way. Mostly because I don't like using vi. Thanks for pointing out my slop - I've fixed my answer.

Comment: You aren't forced to use vi. If you prefer something like pico, use the command "VISUAL=/usr/bin/pico crontab -e". Better yet, if you have and editor preference, set the environment variables VISUAL and EDITOR to the full path of your editor in your .bashrc.

Comment: @bstpierre - good point.  Although my issue is that the preference isn't stronger than the inertia :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out "ncftp". It would condense your upload command into "ncftpput -u $USER -p $PASSWD $HOST / $FILE", and then you wouldn't need the script at all, just put the whole command into your crontab:

```
0 2 * * * /usr/bin/time -a ~/output.log ncftpput -u $USER -p $PASSWD $HOST / $FILE
```

Comment: I tried to do it how you said:

/usr/bin/time -a /usr/local/apache/sites/consumercompare/upload_test/output.log ncftpput -u nextadvi -p ne#541pal seemyreportsfree.net / /usr/local/apache/sites/consumercompare/upload_test/uploadtest.gif

but the ftp doesn't happen, the output.log is blank and the cron email I get is:  

0.00user 0.00system 0:00.03elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+255minor)pagefaults 0swaps